# INSERT into PostgreSQL using user-defined Type

Tags: postgresql

I have a user-defined type in my PostgreSQL table:

```
  pgm.createType("foo", {
    amount: {
      type: "numeric"
    },
    display: {
      type: "varchar(1000)"
    }
  });
```

Whatever combo I try, I get a syntax error for inserting a value into that column:

```
INSERT INTO "foos" ("bar") VALUES ('{amount:0,display:"0"}') RETURNING *
```

I receive: "invalid input syntax for type foo"

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you are using `JSON` syntax instead of composite type syntax. You might want to [reconsider](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/271249/242866) your data type selection - if you're dealing with `JSON` input, why not put it in a [`JSON`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) column?

```sql
create type foo as (amount numeric, display varchar(1000));
--CREATE TYPE
create table foos (bar foo);
--CREATE TABLE
INSERT INTO "foos" 
   ("bar") 
VALUES 
   ('(0,0)'),
   ('(1,abc)'),
   ('(20,test_value_of_display_field)');
--INSERT 0 3
table foos;
--               bar
------------------------------------
-- (0,0)
-- (1,abc)
-- (20,test_value_of_display_field)
--(3 rows)
select (foos.bar).amount, (foos.bar).display from foos;
-- amount |           display
----------+-----------------------------
--      0 | 0
--      1 | abc
--     20 | test_value_of_display_field
--(3 rows)
```

and to make your input work (also adding missing `"` double quotes around keys)

```sql
insert into foos (bar)
select (amount,display)::foo 
from json_to_record('{"amount":999,"display":"from_json"}') 
     as x(amount numeric,display text)
returning *;
--       bar
-------------------
-- (999,from_json)
--(1 row)

--INSERT 0 1
```